# hook_menu and Access Denied

Tags: routes

Why do all of these menu items return "Access Denied" pages no matter how many times I drush cc all and clear cache from admin/config/performance?

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu()
 */
function caplogin_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['join'] = array(
    'title' => 'Foo settings',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
  $items['join/signup'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'caplogin_unified_registration',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'title' => 'Request Member Online Credentials',
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
  $items['join/login'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'caplogin_unified_login',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'title' => 'Members Login',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Comment: Access denied for everybody ? Or just normal users? You didn't mention if the user accessing has the Role access content BTW.

Comment: Have you given permissions for anonymous user, since you are using access arguments you need to set appropriate permissions else it will show access denied page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the first menu item, you didn't provide any page callback, and `MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK` menu items inherited it from the parent menu item. In this case, Drupal returns a 403 error.
For the last one, the reason can be one of the following:

- The page callback function doesn't exist, or it is defined in a file that is not the module file
- The user account doesn't have the permission 'access content'